# Secured Download Link

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say I have a file in my server and I want it to be available for my user. How can I provide them a download link without providing them the real (direct) path of the file?

Comment: Provide an IIS Virtual Path

Comment: can you provide me a sample code or link for tutorial?

Comment: This is nothing in code - it's just configuration of your web-server. In IIS use IIS-Manager to add an VirtualDirectory to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a virtual directory setup in IIS pointing to the directory/path of the file so for instance;

- IIS Manager - go to appropriate website and right click, add virtual directory
- Add alias of your virtual directory and path (e.g. docs and C:\docs)

Once this configuration is done you will be able to give download links: [http://url.com/docs/file.txt]